# Prevent text autocomplete in WPF ComboBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, combobox

I'm using [this filtered WPF ComboBox control](http://dotbay.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/building-filtered-combobox-for-wpf.html) from Diederik Krols.

I have found that it works fine for almost all cases but that entering in the first letter of any given item in the collection causes the ComboBox to automatically set its text property to the string representing that item, and therefore kill all further filtering. I can't even backspace away from the result when this happens, as pressing the backspace key causes the cycle to happen again.

After much head-scratching, staring at the wall, and drooling like an idiot, I've *finally* worked out that this is actually expected behaviour if the ComboBox has been set to AutoCompleteMode.Append. I need to set it to AutoCompleteMode.None.

[WPF ComboBoxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx) don't appear to have an AutoCompleteMode property.

Is there any way around this, to achieve AutoCompleteMode.None behaviour?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<ComboBox IsTextSearchEnabled="false"/>
```

Comment: AUGH! I've been deleting that line instead of setting it to False because __I'm an idiot__.

Comment: Also, I think you meant the `IsTextSearchEnabled` property, because `TextSearch` isn't a boolean.